# Extracting specific key value pair in a column of dictionaries in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

im trying to extract the 'location' value for each row in this dataframe, the code works fine if i do it for a single row by giving the input in this format, but doesnt work when i try to iterate over all rows:

This code works(giving single row as input):

```
d = {'username': 'vinceXy798', 'id': 3920072465, 'displayname': 'xxxxx', 'rawDescription': 'ðŸ’™NHS #FPBE anti extreme right & extreme left, centrist starmer supporterðŸš§ anti unscientific bigots & racists ðŸš«DMs', 'renderedDescription': 'ðŸ’™NHS #FPBE anti extreme right & extreme left, centrist starmer supporterðŸš§ anti unscientific bigots & racists ðŸš«DMs', 'descriptionLinks': None, 'verified': False, 'created': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 10, 17, 3, 55, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'followersCount': 3151, 'friendsCount': 4847, 'statusesCount': 18548, 'favouritesCount': 14877, 'listedCount': 3, 'mediaCount': 0, 'location': 'Czech Republic', 'protected': False, 'link': None, 'profileImageUrl': 'https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png', 'profileBannerUrl': None, 'label': None}

res = {key: d[key] for key in d.keys() & {'location'}}
```

This does not(iterating over all rows):

```
df['location'] = (df['user'].explode() .apply(lambda x: x['location']) .groupby(level=0) .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
```

Is there a way to iterate over all rows and extract each location(pls find pic of the dataframe)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) to extract values from a `Series` that contains `dict`:

```
df['location'] = df['user'].str.get('location')
print(df)

# Output
                                                user        location
0  {'username': 'vinceXy798', 'id': 3920072465, '...  Czech Republic
```